# Minimal devstack with nova and floating ips

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

I'm trying to set up a minimal devstack that can launch nova instances, some which will have public addresses, and some which will need to open connections to the public network. I'd like to be able to assign floating ips to the instances, and have traffic originating from the instances with public addresses reach the public network.

#### Addressing

Devstack will be running on a single Ubuntu 14.04 box with two physical interfaces. The first interface `eth0` is on 10.48.4.0/22, on which I own the address 10.48.6.232; this is the management connection to the box. The second interface `eth1` is on 10.48.8.0/22 and owns the addresses 10.48.11.6 and 10.48.11.57-10.48.11.59. `eth1` is configured to use the 10.48.11.6 address, leaving a small pool of addresses for the floating range.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.48.11.6
    netmask 255.255.252.0
```

I'd like to use the range 10.48.11.57-10.48.11.59 as the floating IP pool. This makes up the start of my `local.conf`

```
[[local|localrc]]

# Devstack host IP eth1 address
HOST_IP=10.48.11.6

# Private network
FIXED_RANGE=10.90.100.0/24
NETWORK_GATEWAY=10.90.100.1

# Public network
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=10.48.11.57,end=10.48.11.59
FLOATING_RANGE=10.48.8.0/22
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY=10.48.8.1

# Public network is eth1
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=eth1
```

#### ML2

The remainder of the relevant part of my `local.conf` is configuring neutron and ovs to use the public network. I've followed the instructions in the comments in [`neutron-legacy`](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/blob/stable/liberty/lib/neutron-legacy).

```
# Neutron
# -------

PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex

Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
PUBLIC_PHYSICAL_NETWORK=public
OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex

# Neutron Provider Network
ENABLE_TENANT_TUNNELS=True
PHYSICAL_NETWORK=public
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex

# Use ml2 and openvswitch
Q_PLUGIN=ml2
Q_ML2_PLUGIN_MECHANISM_DRIVERS=openvswitch,logger
Q_AGENT=openvswitch
enable_service q-agt

# ml2 vxlan
Q_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPE=vxlan
Q_ML2_PLUGIN_VXLAN_TYPE_OPTIONS=(vni_ranges=1001:2000)
Q_AGENT_EXTRA_AGENT_OPTS=(tunnel_types=vxlan vxlan_udp_port=8472)
Q_USE_NAMESPACE=True
Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
```

#### Resulting network

I changed the default security policy for the demo project to be permissive.

The resulting network routes traffic between the devstack host and the private subnet, but not between the devstack host and the `10.48.8.0/22`, between instances and the physical `10.48.8.0/22` or between the physical `10.48.8.0/22` network and the public `10.48.8.0/22` subnet.

```
      \ destination   gateway     devstack     router1       private
source \              10.48.8.1   10.48.11.6   10.48.11.57   10.90.100.0/24

physical              pings       X            X             na
10.48.8.0/22

devstack              X           pings        pings         pings
10.48.11.6

private               X           pings        pings         pings
10.90.100.0/24
```

Traffic leaving the `public` network should reach the physical network. Traffic leaving the `private` network should be NATed onto the `public` network.  Traffic entering from the physical network should reach the `public` network.

The resulting ovs bridges are

```
$sudo ovs-vsctl show
33ab25b5-f5d9-4f9f-b30e-20452d099f2c
    Bridge br-ex
        Port phy-br-ex
            Interface phy-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-ex}
        Port "eth1"
            Interface "eth1"
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
    Bridge br-int
        fail_mode: secure
        Port patch-tun
            Interface patch-tun
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-int}
        Port int-br-ex
            Interface int-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
        Port "tapc5733ec7-e7"
            tag: 1
            Interface "tapc5733ec7-e7"
                type: internal
        Port "qvo280f2d3e-14"
            tag: 1
            Interface "qvo280f2d3e-14"
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port "qr-9a91aae3-7c"
            tag: 1
            Interface "qr-9a91aae3-7c"
                type: internal
        Port "qr-54611e0f-77"
            tag: 1
            Interface "qr-54611e0f-77"
                type: internal
        Port "qg-9a39ed65-f0"
            tag: 2
            Interface "qg-9a39ed65-f0"
                type: internal
    Bridge br-tun
        fail_mode: secure
        Port br-tun
            Interface br-tun
                type: internal
        Port patch-int
            Interface patch-int
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-tun}
    ovs_version: "2.0.2"
```

The routing table on the devstack box is

```
$ip route
default via 10.48.4.1 dev eth0
10.48.4.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.48.6.232
10.48.8.0/22 dev br-ex  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.48.11.6
10.90.100.0/24 via 10.48.11.57 dev br-ex
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
```

The routing table of `router1` is

```
$sudo ip netns exec qrouter-cf0137a4-49cc-45f9-bad8-5d71340b5462 ip route
default via 10.48.8.1 dev qg-9a39ed65-f0
10.48.8.0/22 dev qg-9a39ed65-f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.48.11.57
10.90.100.0/24 dev qr-9a91aae3-7c  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.90.100.1
```

What's wrong? How can I set up a simple devstack that can host both public and private interfaces for nova instances?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/ (where it already is)

Comment: Have a look here: https://barakme.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/openstack-in-a-box-setting-up-devstack-havana-on-your/